# Is "IN" in this sentence correct grammatically

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, sentence

I wrote this sentence:

> My professor **in** many subjects during my studies at Damascus University and my fourth-year-project sponsor.

I don't know if *in* is correct. Or would it be better to use *for*? Also, is *fourth-year-project's* good grammatically ?

Comment: is the professor "in many subjects" or "in many classes" in his one subject?  Did you have him in 10 math classes, or one math class, one history class, and so on.  The last question could be replaced with "senior year project" or "senior project"

Comment: @Oldcat please can you write the correct sentence in an answer in order to accept it. he taugh me 4 courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Professor X, my **_** professor at Damascus University, who taught me four courses during my studies there and was also the sponsor of my senior project...."

Comment: What does the "**_**" mean there? Is that a typo?

Comment: I just left a space for the subject..History Professor, Economics Professor...fill in the blank.